# plpgsql how can I fix the returns

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating this function and I'm getting this Syntax Error: What I'm doing wrong? Thank you.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURNS"
LINE 1: RETURNS student

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetStudentInfo(P_StudentId students.student_id%type)
RETURNS students
AS $funct$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  SELECT student_id, name, date_of_birth, address, email, level
  FROM students
  WHERE student_id = P_StudentId;
END
$funct$ 
language 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetStudentInfo()
RETURNS SETOF students
AS $funct$
DECLARE
r students%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
FOR r IN SELECT student_id, name, date_of_birth, address, email, level
FROM students
WHERE student_id > 0
LOOP
RETURN NEXT r;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END
$funct$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

Comment: have a look at `return query select ...` and forget the loop